# How to see sql statement in a test that I'm using mock?

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, mocking

I would like to see the raw sql generated by a query in a test where I mocked the db connection.

db.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def get_db():
   engine = create_engine('my_db_url_here')
   db_conn = engine.connect()
   return db_conn
```

users.py

```
import db
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

def get_query_objects():
   conn = db.get_db()
   metadata = MetaData(conn)
   table_user = Table('user', metadata, Column('id'), Column('name'))
   query = select([table_user]).where(table.c.name=='asdfg')
   return query
```

test_user.py

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import users

@mock.patch('db.get_db')
def test_user_result(mock_conn):
   # here I would like to see the raw sql of the query that is being created in get_query_objects
   sql = users.get_query_objects()
   print(str(sql)) 
   # result of the print
   # <MagicMock name='get_db().dialect.statement_compiler()' id='123456'>
   # here I would like to see something like 'select user.id from user where user.name==asdfg'
```

How can I accomplish this here on the test? Also I'm open for new ideas to test this function.

Comment: The engine (or more precisely, the driver) is required to generate SQL, so if you mock out the engine the SQL isn't generated.  But I don't think you want to be testing the generated SQL here, only that the function returns objects with the correct attributes.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer, about not being able to see the sql If I mock the engine, thanks XD I'm going to think on some other alternatives to test it.